# How to update a small office of Ubuntu computers without downloading multiple copies of updates? (Ideally unattended)

Tags: updates, update-manager, cluster

I've used unattended and scheduled updates via root cron and am looking to perform updates on a larger scale (using command line: non gui).

Ideally it would download the updates from the repositories once and share a local copy of the updates amongst the machines.

How to keep an office or cluster of machines up to date in a download efficient manner?

Comment: And probably use SSH to run `sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get upgrade` on all the systems.